# La comparaison quantitative?

Tags: comparatifs

Je voudrais demander comment exprimer une comparaison quantitative en français. Je rencontre une phrase que je ne comprends pas:

> A est deux fois moins cher que B.

Je ne sais pas ce qu'il signifie: prix(A) <= 2*prix(B), ou bien 2*prix(A) <= prix(B)? Généralement, je voudrais demander comment exprimer: prix(A) <= n*prix(B)+100 euros, ou prix(A) >= n*prix(B)+100 euros, en utilisant «plus cher que» ou «moins cher que»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quand vous lisez ou entendez cette phrase, la personne veut souvent affirmer que A vaut **la moitié** du prix de B, ou numériquement Prix(A) = ½ * Prix(B).

Dans la même idée, il se pourrait que vous tombiez sur la phrase:

> A est **deux fois plus cher** que B.

Cette phrase est l'inverse de celle que vous avez écrite. Dans ce cas-ci, la personne veut dire que A vaut le **double** de B, soit Prix(A) = 2 * Prix(B).

Vous pouvez appliquer cela pour toutes les valeurs de n. Ainsi, pour Prix(A) = n * Prix(B), on dirait:

> A est **n fois plus cher** que B.

A l'inverse, pour Prix(A) = (1/n) * Prix(B), on dirait:

> A est **n fois moins cher** que B.

Il faut bien comprendre néanmoins que ces phrases sont des **abus de langages**, et que leur véritable sens est erroné, bien qu'utilisé par quasiment tout le monde. Si l'on prend par exemple la deuxième phrase utilisant l'expression **deux fois plus cher**, le calcul réel est Prix(A) = Prix(B) + 2 * Prix(B) = 3 * Prix(B). On ajoute donc le prix de B une fois de plus en réalité.

Néanmoins, du fait que ces expressions sont sur-utilisées dans le mauvais sens, quelqu'un vous comprendrait parfaitement suivant la première explication que je vous ai donné. Si vous voulez être sûr de ne faire aucune erreur de français, pour les deux phrases, il serait préférable de dire:

> A vaut **la moitié** de B.
>
> A vaut **le double** de B.

Pour la seconde partie de votre question, je vois difficilement quelqu'un dire en français l'équivalent de ces calculs avec les phrases **plus cher que** et **moins cher que**. Je verrais plutôt, pour Prix(A) <= n * Prix(B) + 100 euros:

> Le prix de A est inférieur ou égal à n fois le prix de B plus 100 euros.

Et pour Prix(A) >= n * Prix(B) + 100 euros:

> Le prix de A est supérieur ou égal à n fois le prix de B plus 100 euros.

Comment: Comme l'a dit Toto, c'est effectivement un abus de langage. Dire qu'une chose est deux fois plus chère revient à multiplier la chose par trois. Il suffit juste d'y bien y réfléchir et ça devient très clair. Voilà une petite référence avec un exemple assez concret pour comprendre où est l'illogisme de la chose : http://www.achyra.org/francais/viewtopic.php?t=4664

Comment: @Shozs Ce sont effectivement des abus de langage, mais comment doit-on les traiter dans le cas ou absolument tout le monde les utilise dans ce sens? Je me souviens encore d'énoncés scolaires où les questions m'étaient présentées avec ce genre de phrases et portaient le sens de l'abus de langage. Dans une telle question, vaut-il mieux répondre dans le sens exact ou dans le sens le plus couramment utilisé ?

Comment: Je pense que le devoir d'une personne qui répond quotidiennement à des questions de ce type est de préciser de manière ferme qu'il s'agit d'un abus de langage, et ensuite de faire comprendre le sens de cet abus de langage aux yeux des gens parlant français, pour donner tous les outils à ces personnes souhaitant apprendre le français afin qu'elles puissent comprendre ce qu'elles disent, et ce que les autres veulent dire.

Comment: @Shozs Je m'accorde avec cette idée.

Answer (score 1):

Cette formulation est un abus de langage (au demeurant utilisée par la quasi-totalité des locuteurs français), il faudrait dire :

> A est **moitié** moins cher que B.